# Why does running 'bundle install' on the server install development gems? how to force production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on my server, and it installs all the gems and I want only the produciton gems to be installed.

How can I force production gems only? i.e. not the gems found in the dev/test blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bundle install --without development test
```

http://gembundler.com/groups.html